# Globally set mongodb max time on query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using the nodejs driver.

I'm setting a maxtime on my db queries like this:

```
  col.find(
    filter
  ).maxTimeMS(500).toArray (err, data) ->
```

I'm doing it on every single query. Is there a way to set a max time globally so that no query takes more than 500 ms?

Comment: see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152706/mongodb-max-timeout-for-all-queries

Comment: @BertrandMartel Thanks